# Debian or other convention for installing info files in multiple languages

Tags: debian, software-installation, documentation, language, info

I am working on the installation for Maxima, a computer algebra system. The reference manual is written as a collection of Texinfo files. The primary documentation is English, but there are several translations (German, Spanish, etc.). `.info` files are then generated by makeinfo.

What is the general agreement (explicit or implicit) about where to put `.info` files for various languages? I am interested in Debian guidelines or conventions since, to my understanding, they are somewhat more constraining than other packaging systems, so, they might have a clearer guideline, and also Debian is likely to be a bottleneck for an installation which is supposed to work on various systems.

I am hoping to make the installation of English and other languages symmetric in the sense that English goes into an `en` subdirectory just as German, Spanish, etc., go into `de`, `es`, etc. subdirectories. Does it make sense to just put the files into `/usr/share/info/nn` where `nn` is a language subdirectory? (Would the `info` reader be able to find `.info` files in such subdirectories?)

I wasn't able to locate any relevant hints by a web search, and perusing the `.info` files on my Linux system doesn't turn up any apparently non-English files, so I don't have an example of how another project is doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve never seen a language-specific subdirectory used for non-English info files.

In Debian, I can find a couple of “conventions” (perhaps not used enough to actually be conventions), both variants of a language-specific suffix; for example,

- hyphenated suffixes, such as `developers-reference-fr.info.gz` in `developers-reference-fr` (and similar files in other translations), the French translation of `developers-reference.info.gz` in `developers-reference`, or `help2man-fr.info.gz` in `help2man`;
- dot-suffixes in a number of files in the `guix` package, such as `guix.fr.info.gz`, the French translation of `guix.info.gz`.

Neither of these are Debian-specific.